# How to create a toggle effect in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle

I am trying to create a toggle in my angular app.

I have something like this

```
<div ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <div ng-click='toggle-{{item.number}} =!toggle-{{item.number}}>
        <span>
            <span>open</span>  // I want to show 'open' text only when the page first loaded
            <span>close</span> // I want to show 'open' text only when user clicks the div
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to toggle `open` and `close` span based on the user action. What is the best way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close! You actually don't even need to involve the `item.number` within your toggle event. You basically want to flip the `showHide` value and alternate them within your 2 options with the `!` operator.

```
    <div ng-click="showHide = !showHide">
        <span>
            <span ng-show="!showHide">open</span> 
            <span ng-show="showHide">close</span>
        </span>
    </div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/3u7c2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I have ng-repeat and it will create many divs with open and class span. I only want to open/close 1 div at a time. Your way will open all span if I click one div. +1 though

Comment: Look at the jsFiddle, it opens only the spans associated with that exact item, not all of them. (Unless I'm confused lol)